# MyBatis: Map of list based on a column value

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis

Is there a way create a Map of List in Mybatis based on some value of a column in the result set.

To explain my scenario below is the result set.

[image]

This is a result set of Oracle hierarchical query:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM   MA0101.MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION 
    START WITH ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_SEQ_NO IS NULL 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR MESSAGE_SEQUENCE_NO = ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_SEQ_NO
    ORDER SIBLINGS BY LAST_UPDATED_DT DESC)
WHERE (SENDER_NYL_ID = 'T57HI9H' OR RECEIVER_NYL_ID = 'T57HI9H')
      AND FISCAL_START_YR = '2013'
```

Now for every Null(blank) value of ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_SEQ_NO, I need to create a new key in the Map(key will be MESSAGE_SEQUENCE_NO) and the value would be list of all the child messages under that message sequence number.

For example: 
One of the map key would be MESSAGE_SEQUENCE_NO = 12 and the list would be messages with sequence 12, 13 and 15

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

mybatis does not support this out of the box but it can be done by implementing custom `ResultHandler`.

To do this the query should be modified to include the key to every row. Use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, CONNECT_BY_ROOT MESSAGE_SEQUENCE_NO as ROOT_MESSAGE_SEQUENCE_NO
   FROM   MA0101.MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION 
   START WITH ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_SEQ_NO IS NULL 
   CONNECT BY PRIOR MESSAGE_SEQUENCE_NO = ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_SEQ_NO
   ORDER SIBLINGS BY LAST_UPDATED_DT DESC)
WHERE (SENDER_NYL_ID = 'T57HI9H' OR RECEIVER_NYL_ID = 'T57HI9H')
      AND FISCAL_START_YR = '2013'
```

Then custom `ResultHandler` should be implemented. Look for [example](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/ResultHandlerExample) in mybatis wiki.